# about static variable initializing and scope

Tags: c

I have problem with a static variable.

I tried to make maze program by using stack.

At first, it activates currently when I put all codes in same source file.

But after I separate main to `main.c` source, and other functions to `function.c`, an error occurred at static variable.

This is part of code in `function.c` file that problem happen.

I used `EXIT_ROW` and `EXIT_COL` as static variable, and these
initialized at main function.
And I use `EXIT_ROW` and `EXIT_COLS` at other `function.c` file
but when I do debugging this file, `EXIT_ROW` and `EXIT_CO`L didn't initialize at all.

```
void main()
{
    int xsize, ysize;
    FILE *fp;
    if( !( fp = fopen("input.txt", "r") ) )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "FILE couldn't open\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);     

    };

    fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &ysize, &xsize);
    EXIT_ROW = ysize;
    EXIT_COL = xsize;
    printf("%d %d\n", ysize, xsize);

    init_maze(xsize, ysize, fp);

    print_maze(xsize, ysize);

    path();
}
```

I couldn't understand why it happened.. 
EXIT_ROW and EXIT_COLS are declared in stack.h header file.
can u help me why it happened, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please post a [minimal complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In particular, since you are asking about `EXIT_ROW` and `EXIT_COLS` you need to show *exactly* how and where that is defined. But if they are indeed declared as global `static` then of course they can only be accessed within each file. That is what the `static` keyword does. So in fact you would have two independent versions of each of those variables - one set for each file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. so, you mean, static only in same sorce file could access to static keyword? not in same projects??

Comment: Yep. `static` can mean two things:  on "global level", it says "only to be known in this compilation unit" (Your case, apparently. We could say definitely, if you had shown the variable definition and where it is. Within functional scope, `static` means a different thing.

Comment: @ppappiya. Yes. What you really want is a non-static global variable. Or a static variable with accessor APIs. For the non-static variable be sure to define it only once. That is, the actual definition should go in only one .c file, not in the header file. The header file should only contain an `extern` declaration of those variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can assume that you defined the variables with the internal linkage and with file scopes. So each translation unit has its own set of these varaibles.

Any initialization of these variables in one translation unit does not influence on the variables in other translation unit.

Remove keyword `static` in the declaration of the variables. Declare them in some header with keyword `extern` and define them only in one translation unit.